# create sitecore item as pdf

Tags: pdf, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc

Hi i am doing kind of migrating other cms to sitecore now.

So my requirement is to viewing pdf in the respective url..

**Existing site url :** DOMAIN.COM/pressrelease/one

And this will show PDF content in a browser.

**New site expected Url:** NEWDOMAIN.COM/pressrelease/one
[image]

Similarly on my sitecore content i try to create under root one pressrelease item and its child is one.pdf. But i cant able to view my pdf after this when i gave url like NEWDOMAIN.COM/pressrelease/one.

And need expected behaviour is to open a pdf file in a browser as like media (/-/media/pressrelease/one)items are can able to view.

Answer (score 1):

Create AllowedExtensions.config in App_config/include folder(if it does not exist already) and add the following sitecore configuration.The configuration makes sure that pdfs are allowed via URL.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <preprocessRequest>
        <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.PreprocessRequest.FilterUrlExtensions, Sitecore.Kernel">
          <param desc="Allowed extensions (comma separated)">aspx, ashx, asmx, xml, txt,pdf,png</param>
          <param desc="Blocked extensions (comma separated)">*</param>
          <param desc="Blocked extensions that stream files (comma separated)">*</param>
          <param desc="Blocked extensions that do not stream files (comma separated)"/>
        </processor>
      </preprocessRequest>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my case using below solution

1. First i have created one content item **NEWDOMAIN.COM/pressrelease/one**.
2. This item having two fields from my template, like shown below.[image]
3. Then i have some separate Layout file for this content item, In the Layout i have created the code for displaying pdf.(Also in some Layouts i can able to download file too using this approach.)

   ```
   if(mediaResult.mediaItem != null)
   {
       HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
       HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = mediaResult.mediaItem.MimeType;
       HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("inline;filename=\"{0}\"", mediaResult.mediaName));
       HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
       HttpContext.Current.Response.BufferOutput = true;
       // Copy the media stream to the response output stream
       mediaResult.mediaItem.GetMediaStream().CopyTo(HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream);
       // As momma always said: Always remember to flush
       HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
       HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
   }
   ```